# TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str' when trying to write to a csv.writer that uses a bz2.BZ2File object

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, bz2

**Background:**

I need to write a CSV file that I compress before putting to disk as I'm running about 96 processes simultaneously on an SMP and they otherwise fill up the tiny hard drive space I have before I can offload them elsewhere (no, it's not my system so don't ask my how a 104 CPU / 0.25TB RAM / 8 Tesla server only has 2TB shared for all users that is 90+% full). I need to use as many processors as I can since 1 CPU would take me almost 4 years and using 96 drops that to about 2 weeks.

All of the answers to similar questions state that you should use `bz2.open()` with mode 'wt'; however, I have not found any that address using the bz2 file-like object with a `csv.writer()` object and it just does not seem to work. I've even written a script to test all the possible write mode permutations (see below) that reproduces the problem faithfully.

**Note:** I cannot simply to `','.join(row)` which would overwise work with a `mode='wt'` bz2 object because many of the text fields need escaping with line breaks, embedded commas, embedded '\x00' chars, etc.

**Steps to reproduce:**

/tmp/test.py:

```py
import os
import bz2
import csv
import traceback


tfile = '/tmp/test.csv.bz'
row = ['bc22jtr', 118324, None, 'contran', None, 11.5, 9.23, ]


def perr(err, bmode, fmode=None):
    """Func for printing exception info in a less noisy manner."""
    print(
        f"EXCEPTION: wt.writerow(row) → {type(err).__name__}:"
        f" {err}; bmode='{bmode}', fmode='{fmode}'"
    )
    print((''.join(traceback.format_exception(err)[-2:-1])).strip())
    return True


for fmode in ["w", "wt", "wb"]:
    for bmode in ["w", "wb"]:
        had_err = False
        if os.path.exists(tfile):
            os.remove(tfile)
        fh = open(tfile, fmode)
        try:
            bh = bz2.BZ2File(fh, mode=bmode, compresslevel=9)
        except ValueError as err:
            had_err = perr(err, bmode, fmode)
        wt = csv.writer(fh)
        try:
            wt.writerow(row)
        except TypeError as err:
            had_err = perr(err, bmode, fmode)
        try:
            bh.close()
        except TypeError as err:
            had_err = perr(err, bmode, fmode)
        if not had_err:
            prnt(f"WAS OK: bmode={bmode}, fmode={fmode}")
for bmode in ["w", "wb", "wt"]:
    if os.path.exists(tfile):
        os.remove(tfile)
    bh = bz2.open(fh, mode=bmode, compresslevel=9)
    wt = csv.writer(fh)
    had_err = False
    try:
        wt.writerow(row)
    except TypeError as err:
        had_err = perr(err, bmode)
    try:
        bh.close()
    except TypeError as err:
        had_err = perr(err, bmode)
    if not had_err:
        prnt(f"WAS OK: bmode={bmode}")
if os.path.exists(tfile):
    os.remove(tfile)
```

Output:

```
> python3 /tmp/test.py
EXCEPTION: wt.writerow(row) → TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes; bmode='w', fmode='w'
File "/usr/lib/python3.10/bz2.py", line 109, in close
    self._fp.write(self._compressor.flush())
EXCEPTION: wt.writerow(row) → TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes; bmode='wb', fmode='w'
File "/usr/lib/python3.10/bz2.py", line 109, in close
    self._fp.write(self._compressor.flush())
EXCEPTION: wt.writerow(row) → TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes; bmode='w', fmode='wt'
File "/usr/lib/python3.10/bz2.py", line 109, in close
    self._fp.write(self._compressor.flush())
EXCEPTION: wt.writerow(row) → TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes; bmode='wb', fmode='wt'
File "/usr/lib/python3.10/bz2.py", line 109, in close
    self._fp.write(self._compressor.flush())
EXCEPTION: wt.writerow(row) → TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'; bmode='w', fmode='wb'
File "/tmp/test.py", line 33, in <module>
    wt.writerow(row)
EXCEPTION: wt.writerow(row) → TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'; bmode='wb', fmode='wb'
File "/tmp/test.py", line 33, in <module>
    wt.writerow(row)
EXCEPTION: wt.writerow(row) → TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'; bmode='w', fmode='None'
File "/tmp/test.py", line 49, in <module>
    wt.writerow(row)
EXCEPTION: wt.writerow(row) → TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'; bmode='wb', fmode='None'
File "/tmp/test.py", line 49, in <module>
    wt.writerow(row)
EXCEPTION: wt.writerow(row) → TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'; bmode='wt', fmode='None'
File "/tmp/test.py", line 49, in <module>
    wt.writerow(row)
```

**Note:** `bmode='wt'` is not tested in the first loop since  `bz2.BZ2File(fh, mode='wt')` will always raise a `ValueError: Invalid mode: 'wt'` exception.

**Question**

How can I write a compressed CSV with proper excaping and encoding on the fly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer. You need multiple wrappings. Since I needed to use a special open function, I have to have the `fh = open(tfile, mode='wb')` line. If you don't need that ability, you can skip it and just use `bz2.BZ2File(tfile, mode='wb', compresslevel=9)` directly.

In essence, because you have to open the underlying file handle or `bz2.BZ2File()` in binary format, you then have to wrap it in an `io.TextIOWrapper()` object.

```py
import os
import bz2
import csv
import io

tfile = '/tmp/test.csv.bz'
row = ['bc22jtr', 118324, None, 'contran', None, 11.5, 9.23, ]

if os.path.exists(tfile):
    os.remove(tfile)
fh = open(tfile, mode='wb')
bz = bz2.BZ2File(fh, mode='wb', compresslevel=9)
it = io.TextIOWrapper(bz)
wt = csv.writer(it)
wt.writerow(row)
```